# Can't escape space in command prompt's cmd from java

Tags: java, powershell, runtime

I tried like this to execute .ps1 file using Runtime()

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
String path="I:\\my dir\\SendMailPS.ps1";
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell "+path);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

But I don't get expected output. Then I tried directly from command prompt

```
>powershell
>I:\\SendMailPS.ps1
```

This gives me output. But following line gives me error

```
>powershell
>I:\\my dir\\SendMailPS.ps1
```

error:

> C:\Users\my : The term 'C:\Users\my' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Can you use quotes like: `"C:\Users\my dir\SendMailPS.ps1"`

Comment: I used what you suggested as path in double quotes, but no use.

Comment: @anubhava with double quotes, it just print the path as result.

Comment: Hmm can you try: `"C:\Users\my\ dir\SendMailPS.ps1"`?

Comment: @anubhava Same result

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this:

```
String path="I:\\my dir\\SendMailPS.ps1";
```

with

```
String path="\"I:\\my dir\\SendMailPS.ps1\"";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but its not working.

Comment: @niren does this command work on your shell : "C:\Users\SendMailPS.ps1" ? If it works there then the suggestion in my answer should also work.

Comment: this command "C:\Users\SendMailPS.ps1" work without double quotes.

Comment: @niren i meant this command : "I:\\my dir\\SendMailPS.ps1"

Comment: In shell I tried as `I:\\my\\ dir\\SendMailPS.ps1`. it gives me error `I:\\my\\ : The term 'I:\\my\\' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`

Comment: @niren in shell u try this with double quotes "I:\\my\\ dir\\SendMailPS.ps1"

Comment: I tried this `"I:\\my\\ dir\\SendMailPS.ps1" ` with double quote as well, It print me this `I:\\my\\ dir\\SendMailPS.ps1` as result, nothing happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38334/discussion-between-niren-and-juned-ahsan)